# Remote Desktop + Windows Server 2012 + Connect using host name results in "The user account is currently disabled and cannot be used"

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

The server is just a simple IIS box - no AD DS or anything else, running Windows Server 2012 with the latest updates applied.

If I RDC to my server using the IP address it connects without a problem.

If I set up a host name like server.mydomain.com to point to the IP address and use this within RDC then I get an error "The user account is currently disabled and cannot be used." - even though I am using the same login credentials.

What difference does using a host name have as opposed to an IP address to connect via RDC? And how can I change it so I can use the hostname as well as the IP.

It should be noted I do not have this problem with Windows Server 2008/R2.

Comment: How/where are you setting up the host name? Have you verified that the name resolves to the correct ip address?

Comment: Is this 2012 box on a domain?  If so, have you checked your DNS settings?  Did you setup the hostname in the HOSTs file on your PC?  Give a little more info on this and I'm sure I can help.

Comment: The host name resolves to the correct IP address. It is using nameservers external to the server (hosting provider). It is not running on a domain nor does the server run DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it (in case anyone stumbles across this post)- When connecting via the IP address I only needed to enter the username as 'Administrator' and the correct password and I got logged in. When logging in from a hostname (myserver.mydomain.com) then I needed to enter the login with Computername\Administrator. Computername and myserver are the same in my set up.

Comment: It is so simple, but mysterious fix. Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!